# When are computed columns appropriate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I'm considering designing a table with a computed column in Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  It would be a simple calculation like (ISNULL(colA,(0)) + ISNULL(colB,(0))) - like a total.  Our application uses Entity Framework 4.

I'm not completely familiar with computed columns so I'm curious what others have to say about when they are appropriate to be used as opposed to other mechanisms which achieve the same result, such as views, or a computed Entity column.

Are there any reasons why I wouldn't want to use a computed column in a table?

If I do use a computed column, should it be persisted or not? I've read about different performance results using persisted, not persisted, with indexed and non indexed computed columns [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/27/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and-storage/). Given that my computation seems simple, I'm inclined to say that it shouldn't be persisted.

Comment: make all your columns in the calculations not null and place a default on the column.  The computed column is now ColA+ColB.

Answer (score 13):

If your computed column is not persisted, it will be calculated every time you access it in e.g. a `SELECT`. If the data it's based on changes frequently, that might be okay.

If the data doesn't change frequently, e.g. if you have a computed column to turn your numeric `OrderID INT` into a human-readable `ORD-0001234` or something like that, then definitely make your computed column persisted - in that case, the value will be computed and physically stored on disk, and any subsequent access to it is like reading any other column on your table - no re-computation over and over again.

We've also come to use (and highly appreciate!) computed columns to extract certain pieces of information from XML columns and surfacing them on the table as separate (persisted) columns. That makes querying against those items just much more efficient than constantly having to poke into the XML with XQuery to retrieve the information. For this use case, I think persisted computed columns are a great way to speed up your queries!

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, they're most useful/appropriate when they can be used in other places like an index or a check constraint, which sometimes requires that the column be persisted (physically stored in the table). For further details, see [Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) and [Creating Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a computed column called ProspectRanking that is the result of the evaluation of the values in several columns:  ReadingLevel, AnnualIncome, Gender, OwnsBoat, HasPurchasedPremiumGasolineRecently.

Let's also say that many decentralized departments in your large mega-corporation use this data, and they all have their own programmers on staff, but you want the ProspectRanking algorithms to be managed centrally by IT at corporate headquarters, who maintain close communication with the VP of Marketing. Let's also say that the algorithm is frequently tweaked to reflect some changing conditions, like the interest rate or the rate of inflation.

You'd want the computation to be part of the back-end database engine and not in the client consumers of the data, if managing the front-end clients would be like herding cats.

If you can avoid herding cats, do so.

Comment: I appreciate the concrete example.

Comment: If you really have multiple front-ends accessing the same back-end database, a **view** might be an even better solution than a computed column. A view would allow the back-end team to refactor the table structure while keeping the "interface" to the front-end clients backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

**Make Sure You Are Querying Only Columns You Need**

I have found using computed columns to be very useful, even if not persisted, especially in an MVVM model where you are only getting the columns you need for that specific view. So long as  you are not putting logic that is less performant in the computed-column-code you should be fine. The bottom line is for those computed (not persisted columns) are going to have to be looked for anyways if you are using that data.

**When it Comes to Performance**

For performance you narrow your query to the rows and the computed columns. If you were putting an index on the computed column (if that is allowed **Checked and it is not allowed**)  I would be cautious because the execution engine might decide to use that index and hurt performance by computing those columns. Most of the time you are just getting a name or description from a join table so I think this is fine.

**Don't Brute Force It**

The only time it wouldn't make sense to use a lot of computed columns is if you are using a single view-model class that captures all the data in all columns including those computed. In this case, your performance is going to degrade based on the number of computed columns and number of rows in your database that you are selecting from.

**Computed Columns for ORM Works Great.**

An object relational mapper such as EntityFramework allow you to query a subset of the columns in your query. This works especially well using LINQ to EntityFramework. By using the computed columns you don't have to clutter your ORM class with mapped views for each of the model types.

```
var data = from e in db.Employees
           select new NarrowEmployeeView { Id, Name };
```

Only the Id and Name are queried.

```
var data = from e in db.Employees
           select new WiderEmployeeView { Id, Name, DepartmentName };
```

Assuming the DepartmentName is a computed column you then get your computed executed for the latter query.

**Peformance Profiler**

If you use a peformance profiler and filter against sql queries you can see that in fact the computed columns are ignored when not in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Computed columns can be appropriate if you plan to query by that information.

For instance, if you have a dataset that you are going to present in the UI.  Having a computed column will allow you to page the view while still allowing sorting and filtering on the computed column.  if that computed column is in code only, then it will be much more difficult to reasonably sort or filter the dataset for display based on that value.

Comment: Then you can just use a view instead of a table !

Answer (score -7):

Computed column is a business rule and it's more appropriate to implement it on the client and not in the storage. Database is for storing/retrieving data, not for business rule processing. The fact that it can do something doesn't mean you should do it that way. You too you are free to jump from tour Eiffel but it will be a bad decision :)

Comment: " Database is for storing/retrieving data, not for business rule processing" Logic like this is why I spend so much time fixing crap data. If the data must alway follow a rule, to not e nforce it is the database is short-sighted and stupid. Computed columns are oftn used to prevent having to spend a lot of processing time in reports with millions of records when the computation only needs to be done once at insertion fo the record and if the record is updated.

Comment: Well, I call that approach caching. One of the first OO rule is that the class should be responsible for itself, not the database. There are some exceptions when it would be better to do computation on db level (the example you mentioned), but it's very rare.

Comment: P.S. you are spending so much time fixing the crap, because your developers failed to provide a scalable validation layer. This is not a reason for everyone to start programming in SQL :/

Comment: " Database is for storing/retrieving data, not for business rule processing" I quess I can forget everything SQL except "Select, Insert and Update"

Comment: @Davita: OO rules have nothing to do here. If you can do something at the "lowest level" (db level) it will always be better then in the front-end ! That's plain logic.

Comment: Guys, I knew that I would face so much opposition while posting my answer :)  I understand that you are attached to the database, but never forget that a dbms is a means, not a goal :) anyway good luck